# issue on displaying images added into .css file in javafx native package

Tags: css, javafx-2, background-image

Javafx native package do not display any images added into the .css file

As i am using an .css file which is located into my project "/styles/style.css"
where i am givng an scene to get the style by,

```
Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 1080, 800);
scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/style.css");
```

To set an image into css I have tried into two ways:

```
-fx-graphic: url("../images/delete_hover.png") no-repeat;
```

AND

```
-fx-background-image:url("../images/bgLeft.jpg");
```

but i do not worked it out.

where I am getting the color or fonts set into the css file but not images
Can please suggest ...

Comment: So, you say, that if you have an IDE project, it works, and when you package it, it stops working?

Comment: yes. it work fine on project but as i make an exe the images are not displayed

Comment: And when you call "java -jar <result>.jar", does it work right? If not, please, attach list of files in jar (analog of unzip -l method in unix; it is possible, that jar has similar option)... ?

Comment: thanks,but i tried extracting .jar file it contains images,style folder into it.

Answer (score 0):

UnZipped jar I notice that the style.css is convert into style.bss i.e into binary format.

Just make the css conversion to bss false while building the package i.e in pom.xml

`<css2bin>false </css2bin>`

this solved the problem :)